# Custom Post Type archive above Single Post in single.php (same author)

Tags: loop, single, custom-post-type-archives

I don't know if this is possible but I'd like a separate cpt archive type of loop above the normal single post loop.  Something like this in `single.php`

> archive-cpt (loop)
>
> single post (loop

Comment: No it's not... The other is in author.php and this is on single.php

Comment: Sorry about that, misread it ;-)

Comment: That's OK :) they are similar in what I want to achieve but trying to find it which is best

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just need a [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) above your normal post loop. You can copy the `single.php` template and rename it `single-cpt_slug.php`. This will ensure that this loop only shows up on single posts of the post type. If you really **don't** want to use a single cpt template, *you could* use a conditional before the loop like `if( is_singular( 'cpt_slug' ) )`.

To get the most out of this I suggest checking out [The Codex on WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-post). Toward the top of your `single-cpt_slug.php` template you want to define the following:

```
global $post;

$secondary = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'     => 'cpt_slug',
    'posts_per_page'=> 10,
    'orderby'       => 'rand',
    'author'        => $post->post_author,
) );
```

This defines a second query which you can loop through and display anywhere almost exactly like a normal loop:

```
<?php if( $secondary->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php while( $secondary->have_posts() ) : $secondary->the_post(); ?>

        <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
        <?php the_content(); ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php
  wp_reset_postdata();      // Normalizes Global $post Object
  endif;
?>
```

At this point you can then continue with the normal post loop which would display the single posts content.

**:: Note ::** You'll need to replace all the instance in the above code of `cpt_slug` with whatever you post type slug is.

Comment: Don't forget to reset your custom query once you are done ;-)

Comment: Run `wp_reset_postdata()` only if you have posts, add it between `endwhile` and `endif`. It makes sense, why do you need to reset `$post` if nothing has changed it ;-)